# Excel - Max After comparing two arrays

Tags: excel, function

On the following image I have 16 towers on column D with the correspondent applied force on the column E. On the column B I have from the 16 towers, the ones that have an height of 6m.

What I required is to determine the maximum force applied on the towers that have 6m.

I tried something like the function below but it doesn´t seem to work:

```
=MAX (if(B4:B10=D4:D19;E4:E19;""))
```

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4:D19;B4:B10;0)));E4:E19))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or you can use this as a normal formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14;6;E4:E19/(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4:D19;B4:B10;0)));1)
```

[image]